# Is it possible to connect to multiple masstransit queues directly from startup?

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

```
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
        {
            config.AddConsumer<Consumer1>();
            config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) => {
                cfg.Host("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672");

            
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("firstqueue", c => {
                    c.ConfigureConsumer<Consumer1>(ctx);
                });


            
            });
```

I need to take some requests from one queue and then publish them to another queue. This is how I connect to one of them, I tried to add it directly but I wasn't succesful since i can't have 3 arguments

Comment: You can configure multiple Receive Endpoints by calling ReceiveEndpoint more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to connect to any queue when publishing messages. You just publish to an address as [described in the docs](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#publish) using the `IPublishEndpoint`. You *do not* publish to a queue, that's why it's called *publish*. If you need to *Send*, you use the `ISendEndpoint` instance. The `Send` method needs an address.

You *connect* to a queue (and exchange) only when you need to *consume* messages.

With MassTransit, it is recommended to use the `ConsumeContext` if you send or publish inside a consumer. You can use `context.Publish` and `context.GetSendEndpoint`.